# MySQL error when submitting '' in an array

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a PHP loop that's auto-generating an array to INSERT into a table.  But I get this error:

```
Database query failed: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
Last SQL query: INSERT INTO users(id, email, password, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('', 'test@user.com', 'fljhdsfsd', 'John', 'Doe')
```

I've tried setting the id field as No Null and Null, but that didn't help.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mysql is running in the strict mode. You have to pass the `NULL` if you have no value for that column, if the column is `auto increment` you can keep out this column from query.
Once try the below query, I believe this will work.

```
INSERT INTO users(id, email, password, first_name, last_name) 
VALUES (NULL, 'test@user.com', 'fljhdsfsd', 'John', 'Doe')
```

Comment: sir i dont know if Nathan set ID as primary key of the Table but by inserting NULL value on it, doesn't it creates a conflicting error if he sets ID as primary key?

Comment: @johntotetwoo: No it would not generate any error and the auto_increment column must be defined as a key, so it is primary key. please don't use `sir`. reference link for your further reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: NULL returns the same problem. If i pass in "0" it works, but the problem is that I can't always pass in a value for this query. Is there no other way?

Comment: @Nathan: This is probably because you are enclosing `NULL` in double or single quotes. Note that `NULL` is not equal to `"NULL"`. Yes, there is other way, you have to turn off the mysql strict mode.

Comment: What are the trade-offs, performance and security-wise, when turning strict mode off?

Comment: @Nathan: After turning it off, It should not perform data validation checks on DB level and this will lead to insertion of any type of data in any type of column such as if you pass a value `1234` in a `date` type column mysql will not complain but insert it as `00:00:00`. Basically, you will lost the power of data validation checks on DB level.

Comment: @Nathan: I don't think you have any security issue with this if you are properly validating & sanitizing input data with the server side language before sending to the database.

Comment: This did the trick. Too bad there isn't a way to make a single exception for this. Oh well, it does work now.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: FYI, I found a different approach.  I ran my array through array_filter($array) first.  This removes all NULL and empty elements.

Answer (score 3):

If your `id` field is an auto-incremented column then you can simply omit it from the `INSERT` query.

```
INSERT INTO users(email, password, first_name, last_name) 
VALUES ('test@user.com', 'fljhdsfsd', 'John', 'Doe');
```

An `id` will be generated automatically.

Comment: Only problem is the SQL query is being generated dynamically via an object that performs CRUD.  It checks what fields are in the table and produces an INSERT when data is given.  There are times when the submitted data does not include values for a particular field, and this is where the problem happens.  I would like to make MySQL forgive ''. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If id field is auto incremented you can skip that field. If not then read error, it says "Incorrect integer value" and you are giving '' witch is string. In this case before every insert you should fetch max id from database and increment it, or use any other ID generation.

Answer (score 0):

This is happened because your id field in database now contains only integer value. and blanck is not a integer value. Just change the data type on your database.

Just change your datatype id "integer" to "varchar", tick out the "auto increment"  and put a length like "250" field in database, then run your query.

Comment: Please remove the AI(auto increment) option, because varchar do not take AI

Comment: You can not put NULL on your auto increment field